# Retain same connection

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

So I have inherited a dtsx package that basically just moves a bunch of files around.  The good thing it does is it logs every step, the bad part, is that it logs every step.  Currently this one package is doing about 10,000 plus inserts/updates to a log each time it is run, and it runs about every two hours.

I did notice that on the DB connections, the Retain same connection is set to false.  Now I'm not an SSIS expert, but in other languages, not sharing the DB connection caused major drain (as the connect and disconnect to the DB are rather expensive time wise) but in my searches, this seems to just be a solution for allowing transactions across SSIS items.

Should I see a speed increase with this many connections to the DB?  Are there any other issues that might creep up by me setting it to true?  I haven't just tried it yet because the test environment currently takes forever to rebuild into a usable state.

Thanks

Comment: The *only* database thing the entire package does is logging? There's no loading of these files or anything like that?

Comment: no files to the DB.  The only thing the DB is used for is logging.

Comment: Do they have a an Execute SQL Task in the Pre/Post execute event at the package level or is your package riddled with all these logging calls? By default, each component should have it's own copy of the connection so it can be returned to the pool when complete. If there was only the logger in the event handlers, then it'd behave much as if you had RetainSameConnection set to true. I'm guessing though, that is *not* the case and so yes, you ought to get better performance through changing the property. Since you don't have any other database things going on, shouldn't be anything to watch out4

Comment: Your assumption is correct, this is not done thru the event handler, but thru many Execute SQL Task objects that are all over the package.  Just did a quick count, and there are 16 different unique SQL tasks just for logging!

Answer (score 0):

On modern hardware, network connections are fast and increasing parallelism usually improves performance.  That is why the default in SSIS is not to retain the same connection.

I've built similar packages that "over-share" logging when the logic is complex and/or fragile.  Assuming it is logging to a database, I would add a cleanup SQL script at the end that deletes most of the logging data if everything completed successfully, e.g. all the Info and Progress messages.